# move contents of subfolders in archive mirror for video downloads

Tags: video, download, subdirectory, archiving

I need a script (could of course easily write one , but maybe there's a comfortable one existing) to move away (archive) contents of subfolders of downloads of in may case miro video podcast download software;

The subfolders should be created on another disk in same structure and the contents moved and the source folders emptied but kept so miro could continue store the downloads.

The reason I need it, is I want to keep downloading all the time and need just the (smaller) internal disk running and the terabyte store can be powered off.

Comment: This apporach just doesnt work nice as miro wants to download the missing files again. (on feed refresh or another action i dont remember now). Still need to check what's saved in the sqlite db in $HOME/.miro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux or unix use rsync with the --remove-sent-files option:

```
rsync -av --remove-sent-files test-src/ test-dest
```

Comment: yep alright, in this context your hint was fine, just confused option name, so it would be `rsync -av --remove-source-files ... ...`